# trying to use switch statement to move an image in relation to mouse position c++ SFML

Tags: c++, switch-statement, sfml

as I'm new to coding in general I'm sure that my thinking is just heading in the wrong direction with this however..
  I'm trying to get a sprite to chase the mouse on left click. I had tried to use else if statements but only the first 2 statements would run even on multiple clicks.
  I want to be able to say if mouseposition.x > playerposition.x then move playerimage right, and so one for the other directions.
  as I'm using sfml, I've used the below to get the positions of both.

```
sf::Vector2i mousePosition = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
sf::Vector2f playerPosition = playerImage.getPosition();
```

I was hoping to use the switch statement as below but I'm at a loss as to how to create the argument and compare the cases to that argument.

```
if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
    switch()
    {
    case 1: 
            playerImage.move(0.02, 0);
    case 2:
            playerImage.move(-0.02, 0);
    case 3:
            playerImage.move(0, -0.02);
    case 4:
            playerImage.move(0, 0.02);
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand.. are you looking for a pathfinding ?

Comment: this is before collision i just want the image to go to the mouse position when the leftbutton is clicked. there is only a window and a player icon drawn

Comment: Then I would go for a if (mousePosition.x < playerPosition.x) moveToLeft(); 
etc.. but if you keep it in a switch, there will be only 1 movement for each mouseclick

Comment: got it thanx Raakz, I had made the mistake of using else statements before, instead I used a list of if statements now the icon chases the mouse whenever left click is down even when moving around. thanx for getting on the right thought path. I would paste the code but I'm not allowed to use answer button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {

  sf::Vector2f offset;

  if (mousePosition.x > playerPosition.x) {
    offset.x = 0.02f;
  } else if (mousePosition.x < playerPosition.x) {
    offset.x = -0.02f;
  }

  if (mousePosition.y > playerPosition.y) {
    offset.y = 0.02f;
  } else if (mousePosition.y < playerPosition.y) {
    offset.y = -0.02f;
  }

  playerImage.move(offset);

}
```